# Affiliate link tracking through Paypal

Tags: cookies, paypal

A company I help out have signed up to sell their magazine and newspaper products via an online affiliate.

The affiliate link directs users to a payment page on the client site, but they are using paypal for payments which as you know takes you away from the site.

I'd updated the paypal accounts to redirect back to the client site, where the affiliate tracking code sits, but I believe because we go off to paypal in the middle of the payment, no tracking is sent back.

Essentially, I need Paypal to send a specific code (in this case the merchant ID) and the order value when it redirects.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I would send the affiliate ID in the CUSTOM parameter of your PayPal request and then setup an [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) solution to log the transaction in your database accordingly.

The CUSTOM parameter will come back in IPN so you can easily update your system with the affiliate ID.